# validate email javascript: show cross when email incorrect/show tick when email correct?

Tags: javascript

Im having a problem with my email validation script, at the moment my script validates the text in the email text box once the user clicks out of it, displaying a cross if the email is not valid and then a tick if the email is valid, the problem i get is if the user types in a valid email and then for whatever reason if they then go back and type an ivalid email i get both the cross and the tick showing up on top of each other at once.

Does anyone know how i can ammend this to only have the cross showing when email is invalid and only show the tick when email is valid.

Here is my Code :

```
<script>
function validateEmail(emailField){
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

        if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) 
        {
            document.getElementById("emailCross").style.display='block';
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById("emailCross").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("emailTick").style.display='block';
        return true;

}
</script>
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="field_email" name="email" onfocus="document.getElementById('field_email').style.background='#ffffff';" onblur="validateEmail(this);" />
<div id="emailCross"></div><div id="emailTick"></div>
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: look at your code, and compare what you are doing in the "valid" case and what in the "invalid" case

Answer (score 1):

You need to Hide the `Tick` if the email validation fails :

```
function validateEmail(emailField){
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

        if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) 
        {
            document.getElementById("emailTick").style.display='none'; // Hide tick if validation Fails
            document.getElementById("emailCross").style.display='block';
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById("emailCross").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("emailTick").style.display='block';
        return true;

}
```

Comment: this didnt work for me :( im still getting the cross on top of the tick if the user goes back and puts in an in valid email

Comment: @user3488706 Are you sure? Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BN3A/) to see the code, if you enter an incorrect value, it will display the `X`, if you then enter a valid value it will display the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

This should to:

```
if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) {
    document.getElementById("emailTick").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("emailCross").style.display='block';
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("emailCross").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("emailTick").style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: this didnt work, still getting the x on top of the tick if the user goes back and enters in an invalid email

Comment: Then you have to force the validation when the user goes back. What exactly do you mean "the user goes back"? Does he click on the back button or does he just click out of the field and then on it again? You need to fire the valideEmail() when that happens